# How to validate license plate characters/codepoints?

Tags: validation, unicode

Although licenseplates from my country only use [AZ09], this is not true for international license plates. As licenseplates may be added from any country, I'd like to know what the best method is to validate a unicode character string for characters (containing a licenseplate).

Should I just close all unicode codeblocks and only open a few, e.g. Basic Latin, Latin-1 supplement and then whitelist characters?

Answer (score 0):

Latin is not enough: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_registration_plate

Letters, numbers, punctuation and separators seems like a good fit, corresponding regex character class is `[\pL\pN\pP\pZ]`.